# Union type of keyof and Lookup Types pairs

Tags: typescript, union-types, keyof

From types like these:

```
type I1 = {
  a: number;
  b: boolean;
};

type I2 = {
  x: string;
  y: number;
};
```

I want to get types like these:

```
type O1 =
  | {
      name: "a";
      value: number;
    }
  | {
      name: "b";
      value: boolean;
    };

type O2 =
  | {
      name: "x";
      value: string;
    }
  | {
      name: "y";
      value: number;
    };
```

How can I define X so I can do:

```
type O1 = X<I1>;
type O2 = X<I2>;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this hack (improved with @Titian's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342446/union-type-of-keyof-and-lookup-types-pairs/51342467?noredirect=1#comment89660972_51342467)):

```
type X<I> ={ [k in keyof I]: { name: k; value: I[k]; } }[keyof I];
```

Comment: Not sure why you say hack, All I see is mapped types and a type query, all perfectly good things to use, no hack here :)

Comment: You might simplify it to use just one type: `type X<I> ={ [k in keyof I]: { name: k; value: I[k]; } }[keyof I];`

Comment: Thanks! I added it to the answer.